# Visual Source code SFDX not working on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

After having all extensions installed and linking up with my Bitbucket and Sourcetree I am unable to use sfdx commands as it comes up with  “zsh: command not found: sfdx” as well as “zsh: command not found: list”.
Any assistance on this is appreciated.

Uninstalling and reinstalling both the extensions and Visual Source Code itself.